# Why into this JSP page I obtain â‚¬ instead the € symbol also if I have specified to use the UTF-8 charset?

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, utf-8

I am working on a Spring MVC application that use JSP pages and I am expperimenting a charset problem.

I have the following situation.

Into a jsp page I have something like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@  taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Visualizza Prospetto</title>

</head>

<jsp:include page="../layout/header.jsp"/>

<body class="azure">
<fmt:setLocale value="it_IT"/>
..................................................................
..................................................................
SOME STUFF
..................................................................
..................................................................

<div id="outputModaleVariazioneAnticipo"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in this page I have 2 importants things to notice:

1) I specify that have to be used the **UTF-8** charset by:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

2) At the end of the page there is this empty div:

```
<div id="outputModaleVariazioneAnticipo"></div>
```

in which is "injected" a modal window defined into another jsp page through a JQuery function that implement an AJAX behavior.

So this is the content of the page that implement this modal:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<!-- MODALE PER L'INSERIMENTO DELLA VARIAZIONE DELL'ANTICIPO: -->
<div id="variazioneAnticipoModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" style="color: #3b5a76;">Variazione
                    Anticipo</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body">

                ........................................................
                ........................................................
                SHOW SOMETHING
                ........................................................
                ........................................................
                <input id="saldoModale2" type="text" style="width: 25%" class="rightAlligned form-control" value='${progetto.impSal}' />
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Into this modal page I have this **input** tag:

```
<input id="saldoModale2" type="text" style="width: 25%" class="rightAlligned form-control" value='${progetto.impSal}' />
```

then I have a JQuery script that, when the user click on a button, update the value of this input tag, in this way:

```
$("#saldoModale2").val('€');
```

So the previous line should only put the € character inside my input tag.

The problem is that instead see € in my input tag I obtain this strange value: **â‚¬**

The problem seems to be related to the **€** character because if I put the **$** by:

```
$("#saldoModale2").val('$');
```

it perfectly works.

The strangest thing is that I have also tryied to perform this replacment into a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/4720ek9g/1/ and here seems works fine. So I am asking if it could depend by some charset\encoding properties of the file that implement my page, or something like this.

It seems me strange because I have done the following operation:

1) As you can see in the page that include the modal page I have specified that have to be used the **UTF-8** charset by adding this line into the **...** section:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

(I think that I have not to set it also in the jsp that implement my modal because it is only an HTML fragment and don't contain an **...** section. It showuld become a part of the page that include it

2) I have manually setted the **UTF-8** charset on both these 2 pages clicking on the related jsp pages into Exlipse and then doing: **Right Click ---> Properties ---> Resources ---> Text File Encoding ---> Other: and here I chose UTF-8**

But I still obtain the **â‚¬** character instead the **€**

Why? What am I missing? What is wrong? Hoe can I solve this issue?

Comment: In what file is the code `$("#saldoModale2").val('€');` contained? Where is it included? What HTTP headers are sent with that file?

Comment: Did you verify your servlet container's configuration?

Comment: I think you are missing  
`<%@ page ... pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

Comment: @Codo The JQuery script is defined in the same page that contain the modal

Comment: @kryger I am using JBoss EAP 6.1, what have I to check?

Comment: @user980717 What exactly means? To specify the charset have I not only to insert the <meta charset="UTF-8"> into the <head> section? What exactly does your suggestion?

Comment: @AndreaNobili no idea, google for "jboss utf-8" or try Stack Overflow directly. Maybe something obvious you missed will pop up.

Comment: Do as @user980717 proposes. The directive tells the JSP compiler what encoding the file has. The *meta* tag tells it to the browser. For the encoding the properly work, your IDE must know the file is in UTF-8, the JSP compiler has to know it (either via a JSP directive or a general configuration) and so does the browser (either by a HTTP header set by the servlet container or by a *meta* tag).

Comment: @user980717 Tnx it works, if you or Codo (that gve me more informations) put it as respone I will accept it

Comment: @AndreaNobili: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` simply tells an HTML processor, such as a web browser, that the HTML is encoded using UTF-8. It is your responsibility to make sure that is actually true. The HTML file must actually be encoded in UTF-8, and the web server must be configured to specify UTF-8 in the HTTP header that is sent with the HTML (the HTTP charset has priority over the HTML charset). In UTF-8, `€` is encoded as bytes `E2 82 AC`, and `â‚¬` is that byte sequence when interpreted as Latin-1, so something in your setup is not processing your file(s) as UTF-8 correctly.